# Foreach - update value if key already exists

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm collecting impressions of pages via ajax and then storing them in a json file. Loop inserts the new page object correctly. The problem is when i wish to update current page object with new impression my loop creates a new object instead of updating a value of a object that already exists inside the array.

**Workflow:**

- every time a page is refreshed i make ajax post to send the data (page id and impression)
- on server then i load the .json file which already holds the info about all pages
- if the file is empty then i create a new array and push the collected data
- if the array already has a key (id) with same value then it should update the value of impressions key (this doesnt work)
- if the array doesn't hold a key (id) with the same value then it creates new page object and stores the id and impression key

**Expected result** (example after refreshing the pages with the id's below)

```
[
    {
        id: "page-1",
        impressions: 15
    },
    {
        id: "page-2",
        impressions: 3
    },
    {
        id: "page-3",
        impressions: 22
    }
]
```

**Actual result** (items with same id's are not updated but created as new item)

```
[
    {
        id: "page-1",
        impressions: 4
    },
    {
        id: "page-2",
        impressions: 2
    },
    {
        id: "page-1",
        impressions: 3
    },
    {
        id: "page-3",
        impressions: 2
    },
    {
        id: "page-1",
        impressions: 2
    }
    {
        id: "page-1",
        impressions: 1
    },
    {
        id: "page-2",
        impressions: 1
    },
    {
        id: "page-3",
        impressions: 1
    }
]
...
```

**My loop**

```
// If array exists
if ($pages > -1) {
    // Loop thro all the items
    foreach ($pages as $item) {
        // If item exists, update it. Else create a new one
        if ($item -> id == $id) {
            $item -> impressions = $item -> impressions + 1;
        } else {
            $pages[] = array(
                'id'          => $id,
                'impressions' => 1
            );
        }
    }
}
// else create new one
else {
    $pages = array();
    $pages[] = array(
        'id'          => $id,
        'impressions' => 1
    );
}
// Store the array in file
file_put_contents($url, json_encode($pages));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proper code with comments:

```
if ($pages > -1) {
    $impression_found = false;
    foreach ($pages as $item) {
        if ($item -> id == $id) {
            // you have found the impression - update it
            $item -> impressions = $item -> impressions + 1;
            $impression_found = true;

            // you can even `break` foreach as you already found your impression:
            break;
        } else {
            // DO NOTHING
        }
    }
    // This is really a new impression, add it
    if (!$impression_found) {
        $pages[] = array(
            'id'          => $id,
            'impressions' => 1
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I've been stuck for an hour and started to overcomplicate :) Will add the comments also, thanks.